# Why are some fields not available as filters for Community/Custom apps in Rally?

Tags: filter, rally

I have a Rally page that contains some Community apps (e.g., 'Custom List with Deep Export') and Custom HTML apps that are using some code I found on GitHub (.e.g., [Custom Grid with Deep Export](https://github.com/RallyTechServices/custom-grid-with-deep-export/blob/master/deploy/Ugly.txt). Within those apps, when I try to add a filter for 'Color,' I am unable to find it as an option. However, within Core apps on that page (like 'Custom List'), I am able to see and add 'Color' as as filter.

Does anyone know how I can add 'Color' as a possible filter?

Since those same Community/Custom apps list custom fields that we have within our Rally instance (like a project ID field) as possible filters, is there a workspace/server setting that I need an admin to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advanced filters contain a whitelist and a blacklist for fields. The default configuration may not include the "DisplayColor" field. It is up to the individual programmer of the app to decide to override the defaults if it is deemed necessary.

If you want to use that app, you can load the source into a custom app and then search through the code and change the whitelist manually. E.g. change:

defaultWhiteListFields:["Milestones","Tags"]

to

defaultWhiteListFields:["DisplayColor","Milestones","Tags"]